# Converting a time excel formula to t-sql

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, formula, sql-server-2014

So I'm new to SQL (I believe it's T-SQL) and I'm trying to convert a function I used in Excel to SQL.

L2 becomes Column 1
G2 becomes Column 2

```
=(INT(L2)-INT(G2))*("17:00"-"08:45")+MEDIAN(MOD(L2,1),"17:00","08:45")-MEDIAN(MOD(G2,1),"17:00","08:45")
```

What this does is calculate the business hours worked between 8:45AM and 05:00PM.

If work goes from 4:00PM to 9:00AM the next day, the result should be 01:15:00.

If it goes over several days (4:00PM on the 1st to 9:00AM on the 4th) it should be 17:45:00.

I'd prefer not to have a separate function because I don't know how to use them as I'm quite new to this - I'd prefer to have it as something I can write within the `SELECT * , <code here here> FROM db.name` section.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the answer here will totally depend on what the types are of columns 1 and 2 in your T-SQL database table.  Can you clue us in here?

Comment: And does the time returned need to be in specific increments (ie: 15 min blocks) or the exact number of minutes and/or seconds?

Comment: The columns in question are datetime format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) if that helps. Exact number of hours, minutes and seconds required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you don't want this in a function, but they really aren't hard to use and the logic you require for this is too complex in SQL Server to be sensibly contained inline (Though it can be, if you *really* want to be *that* guy).

This function has no error handling if any of your parameters are not suitable, though I will leave that up to you as a learning exercise on `NULL` values, process flows and fully thinking through all the possibilities that you may need to deal with:

```
-- This bit creates your function.  You can rename the function from fnWorkingDays to anything you want, though try to keep your naming conventions sensible:
create function fnWorkingDays(@Start datetime
                            ,@End datetime
                            )
returns decimal(10,2)
as
begin
-- Declare the start and end times of your working day:
declare @WorkingStart time = '08:45:00.000'
declare @WorkingEnd time = '17:00:00.000'


-- Work out the number of minutes outside the working day in 24 Hour Notation:
declare @OvernightMinutes int = datediff(minute                                         -- Work out the difference in minutes,
                                        ,cast(@workingend as datetime)                  -- between the end of the working day (CASTing a TIME as DATETIME gives you 1900-01-01 17:00:00)
                                        ,dateadd(d,1,cast(@WorkingStart as datetime))   -- and the start of the next working day (CAST the TIME value as DATETIME [1900-01-01 08:45:00] and then add a day to it [1900-01-02 08:45:00])
                                        )


-- There is no need to retain the minutes that fall outside your Working Day, to if the very start or very end of your given period fall outside your Working Day, discard those minutes:
declare @TrueStart datetime = (select case when cast(@Start as time) < @WorkingStart
                                        then dateadd(d,datediff(d,0,@Start),0) + cast(@WorkingStart as datetime)
                                        else @Start
                                        end
                                )
declare @TrueEnd datetime = (select case when cast(@End as time) > @WorkingEnd
                                        then dateadd(d,datediff(d,0,@End),0) + cast(@WorkingEnd as datetime)
                                        else @End
                                        end
                                )


-- You can now calculate the number of minutes in your true working period, and then subtract the total overnight periods in minutes to get your final value.
        -- So firstly, if your Working Period is not long enough to stretch over two days, there is not need to do any more than calculate the difference between the True Start and End:
return (select case when datediff(minute,@Start,@End) < @OvernightMinutes
            then datediff(minute,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd)

            -- If you do need to calculate over more than one day, calculate the total minutes between your True Start and End, then subtract the number of Overnight Minutes multiplied by the number of nights.
            -- This works because DATEDIFF calculated the number of boundaries crossed, so when using DAYS, it actually counts the number of midnights between your two dates:
            else (datediff(minute,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) - (datediff(d,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) * @OvernightMinutes))/1440.

        -- If you want to return your value in a slightly different format, you could use variations of these two, though you will need to change the RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2) at the top to RETURNS NVARCHAR(25) if you use the last one:

            -- else datediff(minute,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) - (datediff(d,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) * @OvernightMinutes)
            -- else cast((datediff(minute,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) - (datediff(d,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) * @OvernightMinutes))/60 as nvarchar(5)) + ' Hours ' + cast((datediff(minute,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) - (datediff(d,@TrueStart,@TrueEnd) * @OvernightMinutes))%60 as nvarchar(5)) + ' Minutes'

            end
            )
end

go
```

And this is how you call the function:

```
select dbo.fnWorkingDays('2016-09-04 12:00:00.000', '2016-09-06 12:10:00.000') as WorkingDays
```

You can replace the two DATETIME values about with the appropriate column names to get your desired result inline:

```
select dbo.fnWorkingDays(Dates.StartDate, Dates.EndDate) as WorkingDays

from (select '2016-09-04 12:00:00.000' as StartDate
            ,'2016-09-06 12:10:00.000' as EndDate
            ) as Dates
```